# Retrofit 2.0: Unable to create call adapter for class

Tags: android, json, retrofit

I'm using Retrofit 2.0-beta1. How can I make a simple synchronous request and deserialize a JSON response as a POJO list? This is my interface:

```
public interface ArticlesAPI {
    @GET("/articles")
    List<ArticleResource> getArticles();
}
```

and

```
public class ArticleResource {

    public String id;
    public String name;

    public Article toArticle() {
        return new Article(id, name);
    }
}
```

but I get this error:

> ```
> >  Unable to create call adapter for
> > java.util.List<com.bla.bla.rest.resources.ArticleResource>
> ```

**Retrofit build**

```
Retrofit retrofit = (new Retrofit.Builder()).baseUrl(this.baseUrl).build();
ArticlesAPI api = retrofit.create(ArticlesAPI.class);
```

Comment: how are you instantiating the Retrofit.Builder?

Comment: I have posted the code

Comment: It still does not work

Comment: is it the same error ?

Comment: Yes, the same one. Although I have used JacksonConverterFactory instead. It should work, should it?

Comment: It works!! Thanks. Can you post it as answer? I will accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Accordingly to the code you posted you have to change from

`List<ArticleResource> getArticles();`

to

`Call<List<ArticleResource>> getArticles();`

You might also want to call explicitly `addConverterFactory` to set the converter you want to use

Comment: Can you please explain why that is?

Comment: @Radu *why that is* what ?

Comment: Why has Retrofit 2.0 decided to wrap everything in a Call<T>. I think it's to encapsulate the sync/async behavior?

Comment: @Radu, it is highly possibile.  You should ask square to be 100% sure

Answer (score 35):

This issue can also occur if you are using `kotlin` `coroutines` and the function is not `suspend` function

```
public interface ArticlesAPI {
 @GET("url.../habits/progress/")
    suspend fun getHabitsTasks(): BaseResponse<HabitResModel>
}
```

Comment: Ka-chow! I forgot the suspend prefix. Thank you! :)

Comment: Ops..why android? why?

Comment: Hello @Rahul,I am new with MVVM and corotuines,i got the same problem.Can you help me.Here is my code https://github.com/diptoroy/RetrofitKotlin

Comment: saved the day...

Answer (score 2):

Change the retrofit2 version to latest in build.gradle file

```
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0"
```