# Unable to create call adapter for retrofit.Call<java.util.List<Model.Object>>

Tags: android, retrofit2

My request fails doing a call

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(MyAPI.BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(JacksonConverterFactory.create())
        .build();

// prepare call in Retrofit 2.0
MyAPI myAPI = retrofit.create(MyAPI.class);

**// Debug fails here on line below**
Call<List<Place>> call = myAPI.loadPlaces(3, "restaurant");
```

My interface

```
//  Base search url, trailing slash needed
String BASE_URL = "https://test.domain.com/";

@GET("place/search")
Call<List<Place>> loadPlaces(
        @Query("count") int amountOfResults,
        @Query("filter_category") String category);
```

Unfortunately [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33240648/retrofit-2-0-unable-to-create-call-adapter-for-class) did not helped, while most search results are using Gson and RxJava

Is there a way to get results without using a call?

Comment: nope you cannot get result without using a call

Comment: What is **Model**?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce a model class, in this case a 'place'

Comment: Hmm now that you mention it, I've only ever used GSON and LoganSquare

Answer (score 0):

You can use rxJava library, for that you have to use specific call adapter factory during Retrofit instance creation: .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create()) .
Advantage of this method is that you can easily handle request in background and be notified about errors.

```
Observable<List<Place>> pendingResult = myApi.getPlaces();
pendingResult.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io)
.map(places -> {
    // pre- process places somehow
})
.subscribe(places -> {
// process result
}, error -> {
// handle error
}}
```

See this tutorial: https://medium.freecodecamp.com/rxandroid-and-retrofit-2-0-66dc52725fff#.5h0ecp5dg

Comment: Working on it, the observable does not seem to accept a List. Any ideas? my response is an json array.

Comment: JsonArray is a raw type, it has to be parsed into POJOs classes (use jsonschema2pojo.org resource). Retrofit support GSON parser (you add GsonConverterFactory during Retrofit instance creation).

Comment: I am using the JacksonConverterFactory.

Comment: is it responsible to handle this in a singleton?

Comment: there is 'converter factories' concept - some adapter, used for converting raw type. If I remember right, you need JacksonConverterFactory. Add it during Retrofit instance creation.